# Как изменить цвет в ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

Как можно поменять цвет в ActionBar (android), например на синий?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В файле style.xml пишем следующее

```
<!-- стиль для заднего фона -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<!-- стиль для текста -->
    <style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Ну а в минифесте прописываем нашу тему, например для всего приложения

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Ну и в файле colors.xml добавляем цвет

```
<color name="actionbar_background">#669f36</color>
<color name="actionbar_text_color">#ffffff</color>
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно по разному

Если используется `AppCompatActivity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

Если просто `Activity`:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

Ещё можно задать цвет из стилей, аттрибутом `colorPrimary`, если `ActionBar` это тулбар внутри `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

И ещё много способов, включая назначение атрибута `background` в разметке и назначением стилей там же.

Всё от ситуации зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий пример для случая

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Изменяется цвет фона, заголовка и подзаголовка ActionBar.

```
// настроим панель Action Bar Android приложения
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.DKGRAY));
        actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>")));
        actionBar.setSubtitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#999999\">" + getString(R.string.app_subname) + "</font>")))
```

;

Приведённый выше пример со стилями меняет цвет **всей** Activity, а это не подойдёт, например, в случае превью фото - это превью будет залито фоном и станет "непрозрачным". Я имею в виду пример:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
```