# Как сделать, чтобы для каждого пункта меню была отдельная страница?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-menu

Сделала меню, вроде работает, раскрывается. Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на главную страницу, открывалась страница activity_main?
Как добавить новые страницы и сделать переходы по ним?
это main_activity

```
package ru.romanova.programm

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

это menu_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_head"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_head"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_site"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_site"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_kurs"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_kurs"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_teacher"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_teacher"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_price"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_price"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, чтобы задать действие по клику на каждый пункт меню, реализуйте [метод onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions#handle-actions):

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean =
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_head -> {
            // действие по клику на первый пункт менюд
            true
        }
        R.id.action_site -> {
            // действие по клику на второй пункт меню
            true
        }

        ...

        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Далее, чтобы открыть какой-то другой экран вашего приложения, используйте метод `startActivity`, передав в него [явный интент](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intent.php):

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java))
```

Если же вам нужно совершить переход в браузер вместо открытия экрана внутри вашего приложения, то используйте [неявный интент](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intent.php) с экшеном `ACTION_VIEW`:

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.com")))
```

Comment: так, мне получается нужно добавлять еще активити в папку java?например, для направлений делаю отдельное активити и с ним связываю. А я вот для сайта хочу сделать автоматический переход на сайт в браузере, как это сделать? И нужно ли для таког перехода создавать отдельное активити?

Comment: нет, для перехода в браузер нужно сделать определенный интент просто, я думаю сейчас дополнят ответ необходимой информацией

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил пример как перейти в браузер с помощью неявного интента. Рекомендую вам ознакомиться с основами про явные и неявные интенты.

Comment: вопрос по поводу фиолетовой полоски)) обновила в ответе

Comment: По поводу цвета тулбара тянет на отдельный вопрос. Создайте новый вопрос, либо посмотрите этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489249

Comment: @pentagon2905, ответы не редактируются дополнительными вопросами, задавайте их в комментах или формируйте новый вопрос. Так же если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.